# Adding ID's to dynamically created table

Tags: php, html-table

With the help of another Stack Overflow post I've now got dynamic tables working correctly.
I'm looping though an array and creating multiple tables. This works well.

This is the code I'm using :

```
foreach ($id as $k => $v) {
    $maxcols = $cols[$unit[$k]]; 
    $maxid = $cells[$unit[$k]]; 
    $startid = 1;
```

// maxcols = 4
// maxid = 8

```
echo "<table id='table$v'><tr>\n";
for ($i = 1;$i<=ceil($maxid/$maxcols);$i++) {

    echo "<tr>\n";
    for ($j=1;$j<=$maxcols;$j++) {
        if ($startid <= $maxid)
            echo "  <td class='mark'>ID".$startid++."</td>\n";
        else
            echo "  <td class='mark'> </td>\n";
    }

    echo "</tr>\n<tr>\n";
    for ($j=1;$j<=$maxcols;$j++) {
        $p = ($i==1) ? $j : ($j+$maxcols);
        echo "<td id='$p'></td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}

echo "</table>\n";
}
```

If maxcols = 4 and maxid = 8 I get a table that looks like this :

[image]

Viewing the code for that table I can see each TD has an ID that matches the header ID value. eg : row 1 column 2 TD ID =2 header = ID2

The ID value is being created using this :

```
    $p = ($i==1) ? $j : ($j+$maxcols);
```

If I change maxcols = 2 then I get a table that looks like this :

[image]

However the TD ID values are not matching the Header ID. They go

```
1,2
3,4
3,4
3,4
```

How do I make each cell have the correct TD ID ?

Comment: Can you please mention the value of "$id"

Comment: "If maxcols = 8 and maxid = 4" I think you mean "If maxcols = 4 and maxid = 8". Same with "If I change maxid = 2", I think that should be "If I change maxcols = 2". Similarly, the comments at the top of the code are wrong.

Comment: Probably not related but you open a row that is never closed: `echo "<table id='table$v'><tr>\n"`, I think it should just be `echo "<table id='table$v'>\n"`

Comment: @Andolasoft - ID is an array of devices - that I'm trying to display in the tables. when run I get several tabled all different sizes which is correct.

Comment: @PatrickQ - Original Post updated with the correct values ;) Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
$maxcols = $cols[$unit[$k]]; 
$maxid = $cells[$unit[$k]]; 
$startid = 1;
$idCounter = 1;
…
…
for ($j=1;$j<=$maxcols;$j++) {
    echo "<td id='$idCounter'></td>\n";
    $idCounter++;
}
```

There's probably a way to do it using `$j`, `$i`, and `$maxcols`, but why complicate things.

If you really only want to assign ids to cells that will have values, you could make this change

```
echo "<td id='".($idCounter<=$maxid ? $idCounter : "")."'></td>\n";
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. With maxcols = 4 & maxid = 8 I get on the first row 1,2,3,4 on the second row 2,3,4,5. If I change maxcols = 2 I get on the first row 1,2 on the second row 2,3 on the third row 3,4 and filially 4,5.

Comment: @user214292 Updated with a simpler solution than was I was going for the first time.

Comment: Thanks that works great with one exception.  If I have maxcols = 3 & maxid = 8 the table is 3 x 3 with the last cell having an id of 9, even though there is only 8 entries. anyway around that ?

Comment: @user214292 If you're creating the cell, it should probably have an id, whether you're putting a value in it or not. However, if you really need to do it that way, see my update.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I was just thinking of something similar.